# How to build a 3rd-party executable file into a go executable?

Tags: go, go-build

I want to build `chromium` into a go executable file with `go build`, so that users can run the executable file without installing `chromium`.

```
// my go code snippets
...

import "github.com/chromedp/chromedp"

opts := []chromedp.ExecAllocatorOption{
        chromede.ExecPath("./chromium")
}
...
```

In my study, `go:embed` might solve my problem. However, I haven't found any examples for embedding executable files, just for embedding data files (ex: csv, txt, ...).
I have two questions,

1. How to build an executable file into a go executable?
2. Is that a common practice? Or it's the user responsibility to install the dependencies.